# Is there a defined sequence of events when a Buddhist enters a temple?

Tags: traditions, monastery, temples

As there are sequence of events which happen in other religions, do such things happen in Buddhism also?

**For example:**

Consider Christianity, it starts with a worship, then a sermon follows, followed by offerings and then end with a blessing from the priest.

Consider Hinduism, it starts with entering the temple, a silent prayer, followed by a blessing from the priest.

So, is there a defined set of sequences when a Buddhist enters the (Buddhist) temple?

Comment: Wait, I'm confused. When a christian enters a church, there is always a sermon etc.? I think you are mixing two things: what you do when you enter a temple vs. what a standard "service" looks like.

Comment: @AndreiVolkov It was just an example.  I meant to highlight the **sequence of events** tradition which happen at most religious houses.

Comment: sequence of events that practitioner does, or that the priests do?

Comment: @AndreiVolkov **Practitioners**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the temple and what part of it you're entering.

For instance, I used to be involved with my local Mahayana Temple.  Whenever we entered the meditation hall, we did the following..

1. Took off our shoes
2. Bowed to the altar, with our hands together in front of our chest.
3. After meditation, bowed each time the meditation leader rang a bell (some leaders had us do full prostrations instead).
4. When leaving, we turned to face the altar and repeated #2.

1, 2 and 4 were common to all the Buddhist Temple meditation halls I visited.